# Unable to read value of the property 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Login page. After successfull Login user redirectes to Main Page that is a ASCX Page. I have used `div` elements in it.

```
<div title="Main" id="main">
    <a href="/Home.aspx" id="home">
        <div class="link-title">
            Home
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div title="Contact" >
    <a href="/Contact.aspx" id="contact>
        <div class="link-title">
            Contact
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want that During <kbd>TAB</kbd> key press when focus occurs on particular anchor tag, and then on <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press, it redirects to specific linked page.

Anchor tag is working fine. But what I want is that as it opens specific linked page and page is re-loaded then focus should remain on that specific link.

So that on next <kbd>TAB</kbd> key press navigation/focus moves to next anchor tag. I have used following JS Code but on page load it show me run time error that:

> Unable to get value of the property '`addEventListener`': object is null or undefined

```
var el = document.getElementById('main');

    el.addEventListener("keydown", storeLinkId, false);

    //function stores ID attribute of target link
    //into session storage if enter is pressed     
    function storeLinkId(e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (keyCode == '13') {
            console.log("storing " + e.target.id);
            sessionStorage.setItem('tabbed-link', e.target.id);
        }
    }

    //if there is a linkid in session storage
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('tabbed-link')) {
        //get the id from session storage
        var linkId = sessionStorage.getItem('tabbed-link');
        //focus on the link with the matching id attribute
        document.getElementById(linkId).focus();
        //delete the linkid from session storage
        sessionStorage.removeItem('tabbed-link');
    }
```

I have also tried this code to check that `el` is not null before adding an event listener, but getting no solution:

```
var el = document.getElementById('main');

if(el) {
    el.addEventListener("keydown", storeLinkId, false);
}
```

What should be exact code to handle this error?

Comment: but you have not element with `id="main"`

Comment: See there is no `main` id in your HTML Tag.

Comment: @ all. I have updated my code. Please check now.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle? after fixing id - code seems ok

Comment: @Grundy, Sorry I am unable to generate fIddle. Can you please cross check the code, if any mistake.

Comment: Put the script at the bottom, just before the closing body tag. Or wrap the code in $(function() { ... });

Comment: try see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rof6wzqm/1/), your code work ok. Where you place your js?

Comment: also you have not valid html: `id="contact>` missed doublequotes

Comment: I have wrapped the code in wrap the code in $(function() { ... }); but getting same error. I have external JS file for my javascript code.